# How to solve 1.0000 not equal to 1 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sum

I have a matrix `V`.
I want to test if the matrix equal to one or not.

Sometimes the `sum(V(:))==1.0000`
but when I test if `sum(V(:))== 1` the results always `FALSE`.

How to solve that problem.

Comment: Check their difference and make a tolerance for you to accept them being equal

Comment: do you mean (all the elements of) V==1 or sum(V)==1, show V otherwise readers assume it's a floating precision related problem and you have been referred to another QA. If you start with a closed set like for instance N=10;d=randi([100 999],1,N); V=d./d then you shouldn't have any problem with sum(V(:))==1 check